# Convert ISO Date to Text with javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I convert this timestamp

```
2016-06-05T00:00:00.000Z
```

Into this:

```
Sunday June 6th 2016
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Please show us the code you've tried after googling "Javascript date formatting" and where you're stuck and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended Up using this easy library: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 0):

With the given timestamp, you can convert it into a Javascript [Date Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Then with the date object you get either manually construct what you want or use getTimeString. You can check the full api for date objects on the MDN page.